# Is the span of a compact, connected and infinite dimensional subset of $l^2$ open as a subset of the closed span?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $K$ be a compact, connected and infinite dimensional subset of $l^2$.

Is it possible to prove that $\operatorname{span}(K) \setminus \{0\}$ is open in $\overline{\operatorname{span}(K)}$?

Comment: Still no. Let $K = \{ x \in \ell^2 : \lvert x_n\rvert \leqslant 2^{-n}\}$. $\operatorname{span} K$ is dense in $\ell^2$.

Comment: thanks so much, are there any other hypothesis on K for which it becomes true? thanks

Comment: No, can't be. The only linear subspace with nonempty interior of a topological vector space (over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) is the whole space.  If $K\subset \ell^2$ is compact (and nonempty), then so is its closed absolutely convex hull, let's call that $C$. Then we have $$\operatorname{span} K \subset \operatorname{span} C = \bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} n\cdot C \subset F := \overline{\operatorname{span} K}.$$ If $\operatorname{span} K$ (or $\operatorname{span} K \setminus \{0\}$) has nonempty interior in $F$, all these inclusions are equalities.

Comment: In particular $F = \bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} n\cdot C$. But $F$ is a Hilbert space, hence by Baire's theorem one of the $n\cdot C$ must have nonempty interior. Since multiplication by nonzero scalars is a homeomorphism, $C$ has nonempty interior. And that means $F$ is locally compact. And that means $F$ is finite-dimensional.

Comment: thank you so mush, you are really helpful. all you have written include the connected spaces?

Comment: $K$ can be connected or disconnected, that makes no difference.

Comment: ok, thanks so much, so i have to find another solution for my problem

Comment: What _is_ your actual problem?

Comment: You (I guess) asked a very similar question earlier, to which I provided an answer.  Instead of editing your question to clarify whatever extra conditions you want, you simply deleted it, and my answer therefore along with it, meaning I can't even read it now.  Thanks for making it clear that my time trying to help was really wasted.

Comment: i beg your pardon, but just now I'm reading your last question because I had walked away from the computer. The first question, to which you replied, I preferred to delete it because I thought if i'd adjust my question by adding the other hypothesis then your previous answer was not consistent, I began to edit and I felt lost(I had joined this forum a few minutes ago)so I solved by deleting everything but I absolutely didn't want to do it, I'm still sorry. you are precious to me,I found a treasure in you, now it's late here(Italy)but I have to ask you more questions.I hope you will forgive me.